# IOS certificate and provisions

Tags: ios, certificate, ios-provisioning

I have an issue with the IOS developer, he built the app and when I asked him to transfer it to my account, he told me that he needs the developer account in order to transfer it from his laptop, but when I made some searches it proved that he can transfer it from the connect to mine, when I told him to do that he told me he needs the developer account because he needs to upload the certificates and provisions and this can't happen through connect only through the developer account, the issue is the developer account is sync to my mobile itself so he will have access to my mobile itself, is there any other way to do his cert/prov through another place?

I want my app and the source code, so how can this be done in a way that I will reserve my rights?

is there a need for him to get the developer account?

So far I gave him a developer role in my connect account.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the developer to give you detailed instructions as for what certificates and provisioning profiles should be created and how. Then, you would be able to do it yourself. This process involves some clicks in the developer account portal, some actions in the Mac "Key-Chain" app and some settings in the xCode project. Not ideal but can be done.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I was thinking to create a new IOS developer account but my question will be, will he still need it in the future for updates or this can happen through connect ?